# adding sound effects in agora web sdk

Tags: javascript, agora.io, videochat, agora-web-sdk-ng

I have a web meeting app called [TweetUp](https://tweetup.vercel.app) made using [Agora App Builder](https://appbuilder.agora.io/). Now, I want to add sound effects on user join, user disconnect, notification etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are on the latest version of [AgoraAppBuilder Core (2.1.0)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/agora-appbuilder-core)

Here are the ways you can achieve your use cases

**user join, user disconnect**

In your app navigate to `{APP-Name}/src/pages/VideoCall.tsx`

Navigate to your `PropsProvider` component.

It might look something like this,

```
<PropsProvider
    value={{
        rtcProps: {
            ...rtcProps,
            callActive,
        },
        callbacks, // --> callbacks for events
        ...restProps
}}>
```

look for the `callbacks` props,
`callbacks` props take an object type:

```
export interface CallbacksInterface {    
  UserJoined: () => {};
  UserOffline: () => {};
  ...otherCallbacks
```

If you want to register callbacks for userJoined or offline(disconnect), you can pass the callbacks to your `PropsProvider`

```
const playSound = () => {
    let src ='http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/sounddogs/explosion.mp3';
    let audio = new Audio(src);
    audio.play();
}

<PropsProvider
    value={{
        .
        .
        callbacks= {
              UserOffline: () =>{
                  console.log('User offline')
                  playSound()
              },
              UserJoined: () => {
                  console.log('User Joined')
                  playSound()
              }
            .
        }
        .
    }}
}}>
```

Similarly for message received notifications, you can use the `events` object.
Within your `VideoCall` component use:

```
const {events} = useContext(ChatContext);
```

Once you have access to the `events` object, register your custom events for handling `public` and `private` messages.

```
events.on(
  messageChannelType.Public,
  'onPublicMessageReceived',
  (data: any, error: any) => {
    if (!data) return;
    playSound()
  },
);
events.on(
  messageChannelType.Private,
  'onPrivateMessageReceived',
  .
  .
  .
```

There are plans for releasing a newer version of the Agora App Builder Core, with the new release you'll have access to Agora AppBuilder Extension API's. Extension API's will enable to enhance/add newer functionalities to your app without ever touching the core code base.